# Don't know why typeConvertor doesn't work

Tags: java, android

so i want to put in my table a startDate and an endDate,The problem is that for some reason those fields do not take into consideration my typeConverter or it is not good, i don't know.
What could be my problem?

my Table:

```
@Entity(tableName = "bidObjects",foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = User.class, parentColumns = "username", childColumns = "highestBidder", onDelete = CASCADE))
public class BidObject implements Parcelable,Serializable {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double startingPrice;
    private String Description;
    private int imageName;

    @TypeConverters(DateConvertor.class)
    private Date startDate;

    @TypeConverters(DateConvertor.class)
    private Date endDate;

    //The foreign key

    private String highestBidder;
    private double highestBid;
```

My Convertor:

```
public class DateConvertor {
  public static DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");

  @TypeConverter
  public static Date fromDate(String value) {
    if (value != null) {
      try {
        return format.parse(value);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us more code on exactly how you're trying to populate your class

Answer (score 0):

It is not exact solution to your problem but one thing you can do is to use Unix time so you don't have to worry converting `Date` objects.

Get unix time like this:

```
long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
```

And store that value instead of `Date` object.

You can read more about unix time [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).